# AlertDialog text color and margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-styles

I'm targeting API level 8+. I need a dialog with a title, a message, a checkbox with some text and two classic bottom buttons.
I'm trying to use a standard AlertDialog, and method setView to add the checkbox:

**checkbox.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </CheckBox>

</FrameLayout>
```

**showDialog method**

```
private void showDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setMessage("Message");

    View checkboxView = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.checkbox, null);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkboxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkBox.setText("Some checkbox text");
    builder.setView(checkboxView);

    // First button
    builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.not_now),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            });

    // Second button
    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.help),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            });

    builder.create();
    builder.show();
}
```

My AppBaseTheme has parent "Theme.AppCompat.Light" (/res/values/styles.xml), the same for values-v11 and "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" for values-v14.
I've problem in 2.3.3, checkbox and text have no margins or padding (I've set them in xml), besides text is black as the background. Everything looks fine in 4.4.
I've read a lot of things about this problem, but I'm still confused and without solution. Can you please help me?

Comment: you can see my answer to the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33377490/3346625

Answer (score 0):

You can force a white background of your dialog by using:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10) {
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
}
```

Comment: This way I've only my custom checkbox view with white background, no margin, the whole dialog is still black. Anyway I've a lot of other dialogs with black background, so I can't do an exception for this one. I really can't just apply the same base style to a custom view?