# AlertDialog style when using setView()

Tags: android

The Default AlertDialog looks nice, and using setMessage() one can set its text - easy.

But when using setView(), the dialog replaces the content by the given view, which is fine.

However, I'd like to keep the default paddings/background/style. I searched for a proper style and I had a look at alert_dialog.xml, but didn't find anything helpful.

[image]

How can I apply the default style, without mimicking it?

Comment: Please post your layout code n alert dialog code

Comment: You have to set the margins manually on the views. I think they are on Lollipop 24dp left and right. (aligns with title).

Comment: plz remove all style, give proper margine manually.

Comment: As I explained, Yogendra, I'm looking for a way **not** to enter manually margin, since if the android design changes, the margins will be wrong. I'm looking for e.g. an attribute or style I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an AlertDialog style, that you can set when you create your Builder.

Example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
if (title != null) {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
    builder.setTitle(title);
}
else {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogStyleNoTitle);
}
```

In your styles.xml file:

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogStyleNoTitle" parent="AlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

My styles are just an example of some things you can do - you can just have one dialog style if you want. As long as you inherit from one of the Dialog.Alert styles, you should be good to go.

You will still have to set the padding up yourself. I looked at the material design guidelines, and the margins are 24dp.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

AlertDialog alert = b.create();
alert.setView(view, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This sets margins to zero, this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the margins you can use wrap your Layout in a FrameLayout and add the margins in your Layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dialog_margin_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dialog_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dialog_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dialog_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dialog_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dialog_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please enter the email address of the person you would like to follow, this person will be notified." />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the source code of AppCompat

https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/HEAD/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_material.xml

this is an example of layout for a Dialog custom view that looks good

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_top_material"
    android:paddingLeft="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
    android:paddingRight="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_top_material">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that it is not raccomanded to use private values, such as abc_dialog_padding_top_material, but I didn't find a better solution.